# Filtering context for render_block function

Tags: block-editor

I am trying to use render_block within a function called from the WP admin via AJAX

The render_block returns null/empty however if I run my function using the `wp` hook returns the rendered HTML for the block.

I beleive that it is failing due to the fact there is no valid `context` for the render_block as we're not within a post object at all.

The purpose of this is converting a custom third party block to html.

This function that I have works perfectly:

```
function test() {
    global $post;
    $htmlBlock = '';
    if ($post->ID === 535) {
    
        $content = $post->post_content;
    
        $parsed_blocks = parse_blocks($content);
    
        foreach ($parsed_blocks as $blockKey => $block) {
            if ($block['blockName'] === 'f/f-builder') {
    

                // Render the block from array to HTML
                $rendered = render_block($block);
    
                // Replace the img tag with inline styles
                $rendered = str_replace('img', 'img style="opacity: 1; filter: blur(0px); width:100%;"', $rendered);
    
                $rendered = str_replace('data-src', 'src', $rendered);

                // Update the block's content directly
                $parsed_blocks[$blockKey]['blockName'] = 'core/html';    
                $parsed_blocks[$blockKey]['innerHTML'] = $rendered;
                $parsed_blocks[$blockKey]['innerContent'][0] = $rendered;
                unset($parsed_blocks[$blockKey]['attrs']);

            }
        }
    
        // Serialize the modified blocks once after the loop
        $updated_content = serialize_blocks($parsed_blocks);
    
        $postNew = array(
            'ID' => $post->ID,
            'post_content' => $updated_content
        );
    
    
        // Update the post with the modified content
        // wp_update_post($postNew);
    }


}

add_action('wp_footer', 'test');
```

I am unable to post the entire function for my ajax call however below is an abreviated version which does not work

```
function my_function($postID) {

    $newWPContent = '';
    
    $response['status'] = 'default';

    // get the content of the post
    $postContent = get_post_field('post_content', $postID);


    // parse the blocks
    $blocks_array = parse_blocks($postContent);

    // loop through the blocks
    foreach ($blocks_array as $blockKey => $block) {

        $blockName = $block['blockName'];

        if (strpos($blockName, 'f-block') !== false) {
            $blockName = 'f-block';
        }

        $response['message'][] = 'blockName: ' . $blockName;
       
        switch ($blockName){
            case 'f-block':
                /** DO STUFF **/
                break;
            case 'f/f-builder':

                    // Render the block from array to HTML
                    $rendered = render_block($block);
        
                    // Replace the img tag with inline styles
                    $rendered = str_replace('img', 'img style="opacity: 1; filter: blur(0px); width:100%;"', $rendered);
        
                    $rendered = str_replace('data-src', 'src', $rendered);

                    // Update the block's content directly
                    $parsed_blocks[$blockKey]['blockName'] = 'core/html';    
                    $parsed_blocks[$blockKey]['innerHTML'] = $rendered;
                    $parsed_blocks[$blockKey]['innerContent'][0] = $rendered;
                    unset($parsed_blocks[$blockKey]['attrs']);


                break;
            case 'default':
                $response['message'][] = 'Skipping...';
                break;

        }

    }
    


    // update the post content
    $post = array(
        'ID' => $postID,
        'post_content' => serialize_blocks($blocks_array)
    );

    wp_update_post($post);

    return $response;
}
```

In the `f/f-builder` case, $rendered is empty unlike in the `test` function where rendered has the HTML. The one difference between these two functions is one is called via AJAX from WP Admin and one is triggered by the `wp_footer` action.

Comment: can you add code to your question? Note that there's a dedicated endpoint used by the block editor for rendering blocks if that's what your AJAX is for. Also what blocks are you trying to render? For a plain heading or paragraph it shouldn't matter but for some blocks it's important to know, e.g. post titles or excerpts. How you've parsed and structured the block before going into `render_block` is also important

Comment: @TomJNowell thanks for replying. I ahve updated the post with both the working and not-working functions. The blocks in question are from a third-party plugin which I am trying to convert to raw html. This works when triggering my function via wp_footer however not when triggering from ajax within admin

Comment: thanks for adding code, is the block you're rendering getting its HTML from a `save` component in JS? My understanding of this is that by modifying the block like that it's no longer going to validate if it were the original block, and there's a chance things could get stripped out if it's server rendered. Instead, it might make more sense to use the block rendering filters to modify its final output based on the current post so that the post content can remain untouched and the editor can still be used with the original block

Comment: @TomJNowell the idea is to remove the dependancy from the original block completely so the plugin can be disabled. All of the block content are stored as JSON in the block attributes. The render_block works when called from the frontend on the post page however not from the ajax so I am assuming it is due to not being within the post content?

Comment: it's possible the plugin that implements that block has conditional behaviour of its own, e.g. don't register blocks on AJAX handlers. Is your AJAX handler a REST API endpoint or the old Admin ajax? How is it getting `$postID`? Is the block you're trying to render and replace server rendered?

Comment: we're using old admin ajax for this one.  we have an array of post IDs that we pass to a function which then calls this function and passes $postID. I'm honestly not sure if the block is server rendered or not - any suggestions on how to check this?

Comment: if you look at the raw post HTML in the database is the blocks HTML there or just its block markup comments? And can you see it change its output based on context or location/page on the frontend without resaving/updating the post/page? Note that a block that generates its output as static HTML in JS can still have it overwritten via a render callback at runtime. Also  if you disable the plugin the blocks and their HTML should still be there, minus any JS/CSS, the block editor won't like that they're missing but converts them to HTML blocks if you try to interact with them

Comment: server rendered === it has parts that execute PHP when it's displayed, aka it's rendered on the server, not in JS on the browser when saving in the editor